# WiX Burn BootstrapperApplication: Is it possible to silence the Uninstall UI for the bundle and only display the UI for one of the MSI packages?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

If you have a burn bundle that uses the built-in WiX Bootstrappre UI and this bundle contains many MSI packages. Is it possible to silence the Bootstrapper UI on uninstall and only display the UI of one the MSI packages?

Comment: An installed package is referenced by one or more bundles managed by burn. What would be shown if that MSI wasn't due to be removed? Also, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2540593/2226988) about MSI uninstall UIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to create your own Managed Bootstrapper Application (MBA).

I recommend reading this [book](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/wix-36-developers-guide-windows-installer-xml) by Nick Ramirez. There is a great chapter that explains exactly how to do this and the source code that comes with this book can easily be modified to suit your needs.

There is also a good [blog](http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/) by Bryan Johnston that might be enough to get you on your way.