# WiX uninstall GUI

Tags: user-interface, wix, customization, uninstallation

I'm creating an installer using wix for my project. For the installation of the project, wix uses a GUI 
based on WIXUI_Mondo. When the application is uninstalled from control panel, the user just sees a small box with a progress bar. But i want to add a window asking the user if he made a backup of the configuration file for future use. In that window i also want to add two buttons one to proceed the uninstallation and another to abort the uninstall process.

I can't find anything on google about this, so do you guys know if this is possible and how i can achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't Windows Installer use the UI in the .msi file during removal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540593/why-wont-windows-installer-use-the-ui-in-the-msi-file-during-removal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by setting the [ARPNOREMOVE property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367591(v=vs.85).aspx). This will disable the Remove button so users have to run the Modify button to activate uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no UI during uninstalling. The only way is a custom action (e.g. from DLL) with a dialog window.

Comment: Could you share some examples over internet where described this approach?